# not sure if its just my computer, but I cannot play a safari video

Tags: video, safari, mp4

not sure if its just my computer, but I cannot play a safari video in the Safari browser:
https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/apple-vision-pro/2023/7e268c13-eb22-493d-a860-f0637bacb569/anim/foundation-spatial-computing/large.mp4

If you copy the apple video above and paste in Safari, it doesn't work